# Creating an Eclipse plug-in to display content assist regardless of cursor location

Tags: eclipse, plugins, content-assist

I'm working on some reflection stuff using Java across XML files.  The process would be made much faster and less prone to error if I could get content assist to behave like a tree in a small window off to the side, but more than by my current cursor location.

My question is can this really be done without reinventing the wheel too much?  Essentially I want to display a list of classes, choose a class, then drill down a TreeView similar to the outline view Eclipse has for a current open file and at some point I click a button below and it generates the desired XML formatted text I would have typed manually, this is generated based on whatever in the tree I have highlighted.

I've designed and begun work on the front and back end, but the piece that keeps eluding me is harnessing Eclipse's content assist to gather a list of practically anything I could possibly call in a given project.

Can this be done?  I've been combing Eclipse's documentation for a few days and fighting with the source download dying halfway repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% if that's it but I had an eclipse plugin with spider in it's name in mind, which does what you described.

Maybe it is this one: http://eclipse-plugins.2y.net/eclipse/plugin_details.jsp?id=202

Furthermore when writing Eclipse plugins, it is useful to press ctrl+shift+f1 (eclipse plugin spy) once having worked in the pde this should be possible.
It shows you info about all possible extensionpoints refering to your current view.